# Apache in VM serving blank pages

Tags: apache-2.4, virtual-machines, virtualbox

I run a Debian VM as my development environment, running Apache v 2.4.10. Until yesterday it has been working fine but as of this morning any page i try and visit in the browser that resolves to the VM displays completely blank. Even non-existent pages display as blank.

No errors appear in the apache error logs. Visiting the page locally on the VM works fine. I can ping the VM fine from the Windows machine.

I have not touched the default apache.conf but my vhosts file looks like this:

```
<Directory /sites>
    Options +Indexes +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
    Allow from all
</Directory>
.... and then a bunch of vhosts.
```

As I say though this has all been working fine until yesterday.

I apologise there is not much to offer here, but I've checked all the basics and can't surmise why this would be happening. I would appreciate any help; thanks in advance.

A weird thing to note: I dual boot Windows and Kubuntu, and share the Virtualmachine between the two OSs (the VM sits on its own NTFS partition). If I boot into Linux and run up the virtualmachine identically, it works fine! All pages work! EXCEPT for when you make a cUrl request - then that returns no content. Not sure if related. This would suggest that something about the way that windows and curl request pages is different to the way the same browsers in linux do???

This is my VM's interfaces file:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

allow-hotplug eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp

allow-hotplug eth2
iface eth2 inet static
    address 192.168.56.10
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    network 192.168.56.0
    broadcast 192.168.56.255

allow-hotplug eth1
iface eth1 inet static
    address 192.168.20.198
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    network 192.168.20.0
    broadcast 192.168.20.255
```

Virtualbox has three interfaces set, 1 NAT, 1 Bridged Adapter, and 1 host-only adapter.

Comment: What exactly the dev tools of the browser (network tab) said? Sometimes underhood the browser give more data than a just blank page.

Comment: Ah doy. Right so the console is returning a 404 not found header. I also tried disabling apache and it made no difference. So clearly I was right to think that the traffic just isn't getting through in the first place.

Comment: Actually the header is 404 Not Found (from cache). Not sure what that means.

Comment: What IP you are using to try to reach the Apache from your Window? Pls check that Apache is listening on that interface executing inside the VM `sudo netstats -puntan | grep apache`

Comment: Yep I get a 443 and 80 listen entry for 192.168.56.10, which is the IP I am attempting to use.

Comment: That mean that the browsers didn't make any request at all becuase it already made before and took the *resource* from cache. Can you pls execute telnet from windows to the apache? `telnet apache_ip 80`

Comment: I tried that previously, but just tried again. It appears to connect successfully but gives no output. When I type in, the cursor moves but no characters appear.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45516/discussion-between-gsi-frank-and-raiden616).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a troubleshooting session with @Raiden616 by chat we solved several problems, ip conflict and apache listening on wrong address. Was fun ;)